# Word 2016: paragraph spacing not working - paragraph stuck to page top

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I have a title line sentence (1-line paragraph) "Chapter 2: Literature Review" that needs to have a 72 pt paragraph spacing before the line. The line starts on a new page following a page break from the end of Chapter 1.

The paragraph is Normal style: double spaced, no indent, 0 before spacing, 0 after spacing. When I try to add the 72 pt spacing before, the paragraph spacing dialog shows a 72 pt value in the before space box, but the paragraph is still glued to the top of the page.

How can I get this first chapter title to move down with 72 pt space before? Should I just create a new style? I can't figure out what's holding it at the top of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Creating a new independent style didn't allow the before spacing to work. Paragraph is still fixed at top of page. This is a template that I am submitting for school. I can't just add carriage returns to make the space.

Comment: Fixed the problem with a hard section break on the page above

Answer (score 4):

Without having access to your document, it is hard to tell if this answer will work for you. I suspect that the problem is you might have the "Don't add space to paragraphs of the same style" selected.

Right click your paragraph, select "Paragraph". Under the "Indents and Spacing" tab, deselect "Don't add space to paragraphs of the same style".

If this does not work, check the options within the "Lines ans Page Break" tab in the "Paragraph" window, and deselect unnecessary options.

If it still is not working, repeat both of these steps for the paragraphs above and below the paragraph you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a ***frame***.

1. Create or modify a paragraph **style**
2. format (edit) the **Paragraph** settings for the style:

   - set the amount of spacing you want before the paragraph (ex: `72pt`)
   - set a `Page break before` the paragraph (*Line and Page Breaks > Pagination*)
3. format (edit) the **Frame** settings for the style:

   - set the text wrapping to `None`
4. Save the changes to your style (`OK` button)

The paragraph will now have the spacing above it *within the frame.*

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft word veteran here. If you're using word 16-18, follow these instructions:

- Select all you text.
- Click on the <kbd>Home</kbd> tab.
- Then, to the right of paragraph, where there are squares that say `AaBbCcDd`, click the <kbd>no spacing</kbd> one.
- If you had centered text, make the text centered again as it will all go to the left.